# Make Vbscript to run on linux environment

Tags: unix, vbscript

I had written a code so that it can read data from a textfile and pop up IP address and send an email in VBScript.

The code ran successfully.

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Your File Name Here.txt", ForReading)

strSearchString = objFile.ReadAll

objFile.Close

Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

objRegEx.Global = True   
objRegEx.Pattern = "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"

Set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(strSearchString)  

If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
    For Each strMatch in colMatches   
       Wscript.Echo strMatch.Value
    Next
End If
```

The requirements have been changed and it is required to run the same process in unix server, so I have to write VBScript so all the above happens in unix.

Comment: And what have you already tried? Are you getting errors? What languag are you trying to rewrite this in? Stack Overflow is not a forum for doing the work for you, it's for answering questions when you are trying to do it yourself.

Comment: Ya i know, i just want a basic idea(like can we run the same script on unix env) or should i change the entire code??Where should i start?I am new to working on unix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't run VBScript on Linux/Unix. You need to re-implement your script in a language that is available on those platforms, like shell (bash, ksh, (t)csh, ...), Perl, Python, or Ruby.

Since your script seems to be extracting IP addresses from text files I'd say that a shell script would be your best choice here. On Linux distributions the default shell usually is `bash`, so I suggest you start with the [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html). The tool you're looking for is [`grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html). Use it with the parameters `-P` (Perl-style expressions) and `-o` (show matches only):

```
grep -Po "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}" /path/to/your.txt
```

Also, the regular expression could be shortened by grouping dot-number segments, e.g. like this:

```
grep -Po "\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}" /path/to/your.txt
```

If you want to run this from a script, the file should look somewhat like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -Po "\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}" /path/to/your.txt
```

The [shebang](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang) defines what interpreter should be used for executing the content.

Comment: Well said,thnx for the info. Should i write a script in .sh format for automation in unix? Can i verify the result in window command prompt?

Comment: @KrishKrishna I'd recommend running it from a script (see updated answer). While running it directly is also possible, it'd require some creative quoting/escaping, so it's simpler to put it in a script and run that. Whether or not you can verify the result depends on how you run the script on the remote host. [`plink`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) for instance will return the output of the command.

Comment: Great help appreciate it .Thanks